# JQuery DataTableset.net first and last events?

Tags: jquery, events, datatables

I have a dataset which is loaded in JQuery and is shown as a table through JQuery DataTable.net

I  issue a destroy and I create the table again depending on specific parameters:

```
    $('#mytables').DataTable().destroy();
    $("table tbody").empty();
    $.each(myobject, function(i, obj) {
        counter++;
        $("table tbody").append( 
            "<tr>" +
            "<td id=\"s"+obj.Session_ID+"\" class=\"list\">"+           
                counter + 
            "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
    })

    $('#mytables').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        paging: false,
            "columnDefs": [ {
              "targets": 'no-sort',
              "orderable": false,
        } ]
    } );
```

As sometime it could take one second or more I would like to place a "loading" div on the page and remove it once the datatable is ready.

```
<div class="modal2"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>  

$("body").addClass("loading");  

$("body").removeClass("loading");
```

Problem is that I tried practically all the DataTables events but either they are not executed in the order I expected (so the loading div remains visible) or they happen too fast to see the loading div.

In which events should I put the code that loads and unloads my "loading" div?

NOTE: The data is NOT retrieved through AJAX

***EDIT***

Following code, which according to documentation should work, does hide the "loading" modal BEFORE the table is actually redrawn...

```
    $('#mytables').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        paging: false,
            "columnDefs": [ {
              "targets": 'no-sort',
              "orderable": false,
        } ],
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                        $("body").removeClass("loading");  //doesn't work... it has no time to show the loader... :-(
                        console.log('done');
                    }
    });
```

**EDIT2**

Ok, I've sorted my issue: actually I loaded too much static content (200kb) in the page to be loaded into a javascript variable and Chrome did complaint about the long time it was taking.

That's the reason why I had many seconds without either activity or "loading" div.

I moved the static content to an ajax call (so that the data loading is now asynchronous) and I used "beforeSend" and "complete" ajax events to add and remove the "loading" div.

**NOTE** for datatables:

I tried to do the same on the datatables events (in case of search/sort) but without success (not a big issue anyway for me now as the redraw happen now fast)...

Answer (score 2):

`preInit` event is emitted by DataTables when a table is being initialised and is about to request data.

Docs: [preInit](https://datatables.net/reference/event/preInit)

`initComplete` event is emitted when your table has fully been initialised.

Docs: [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)

Comment: Nope... unfortunately in practive, initComplete happens before the table is really fully prepared...

Comment: Did you use preInit and how you have applied .loader div before initialization of datatable.

Comment: I added the loading div when I click a select option which afterwards regenerate the table

Comment: Looks like you messed up somewhere. I am also using datatable, and worked perfectly what I am trying todo. Data table is stable and well tested by millions.

Comment: Certainly can be I made a mistake somewhere but is very weird that the events get called almost simultanuosly... I suspect it has to do with destroying and recreating the table afterwards...

Comment: Ok, I've sorted my issue: actually I loaded too much static content (200kb) in the page to be loaded into a javascript variable and Chrome did complaint about the long time it was taking. I moved everything to an ajax call and I used beforeSend and complete events to add and remove the "loading" div. I tried to do the same on the datatables events but without success (not a big issue anyway for me now as the redraw happen now fast)

Answer (score 1):

I made you a plugin that should work as you like.

Read the comment to understand how it work.

```js
// Jq plugin
(function ($)
{
  jQuery.fn.loader = function (parent)
 {
    var parent = $(this);
    var loader;
    var timeout;
    var helper = {
    start: (func)=>{
    helper.stop();
    // if operation get longer then 100ms then start the loader
    // you could inc or dec as you like
    timeout= setTimeout(()=>{
       loader= $('<div class="loading"> </div>');
       parent.append(loader);
       },100) 
        helper.operation(func);
       return helper;
    },
    stop: ()=>{
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      parent.children(".loading").remove();
      return helper;
    },
    operation: function(func){
    // this is a test only you can dec from 1000ms to 100
      setTimeout(()=> {
      func(helper);
      },1000);
      return helper;
    }
   };
   return helper;
}
    
}(jQuery));



var helper = $("body").loader().start((loader) =>{
// your operations eg destroy table
var count =0;
while(count<10000)
count++
loader.stop()
});
```

```css
.loading{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:black;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}

.loading::before{
content:"loading";
color:white;
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dt"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alen, but my problem is not how to show the "loading" modal: actually my code works well on that on other pages. Problem is that jquery dataset issues a initComplete event before the table is actually redrawn on the browser... so actually I don't know when to hide again the modal

Comment: I think `initComplete`  complate triggerered after the table render but its to fast that you dont see it. if you render the table with ajax you would see the loader. but there is actually a good workout that i gave you, with the settimeout, so you could atleast show a loader event without ajax.

Comment: Yes, problem is that my user still is "stuck" for a couple of seconds without a proper notice...

Comment: Yes and thats why you have settimeout on the loader, so the thread dose not freeze, that was the idee anyway. did you test the plugin ?